# пропадает форма поиска

Tags: html, jquery, css, slider

Добрый день. вот код файла index.php

https://pastebin.com/NJugHC6m

на слайдере есть форма поиска. сам слайдер на Jquery и при переходе на другую картинку форма поиска тоже пропадает:

как это исправить? спасибо

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6vWL.jpg - тут есть форма поиска

Comment: а тут уже нет https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReCer.jpg

Comment: А вы не могли бы оставить минимально-необходимый для воспроизведения ошибки код?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/NJugHC6m ссылка на код там все есть

Comment: Вот именно, что всё, т.е. у вас проблема может быть в паре строчек кода, но вы предлагаете лопатить все 1к строк

Comment: ok https://pastebin.com/isLHfJ28 эта укороченная версия код с вырезанным php где только слайдер и форма поиска

Comment: а также вот ссылка на сам сайт на всякий случай http://geosky.ge/index2.php